What is known about the Jacobian group of Cayley graphs?
Question 1. For which Cayley graphs is the Jacobian group known?
Question 2. Are there any general principles that can help compute the Jacobian for particular classes of Cayley graphs?
Let us consider a finite group  and a chosen generating set . Using this setup, we construct the Cayley graph (,), where the vertices correspond to the elements of , and edges are determined by the generators in .
The Jacobian of a graph (also known as the critical group, sandpile group, or Picard group) is an abelian group associated with the graph’s Laplacian matrix. This group captures important combinatorial and algebraic properties of the graph, such as spanning tree enumeration and network dynamics. A formal definition of the Jacobian can be found in the following reference:
https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/sandpile.html
What is already known (examples):

Gluing of graphs and their Jacobians by A. Chilelli and J. Jun (Research on the structure of the Jacobian for the gluing of ordinary cycles);
On the Jacobian group of a cone over a circulant graph by L. Grunwald and I Mednykh (Investigation of the structure of the Jacobian for Cayley graphs of cyclic groups);
Critical groups of arithmetical structures on star graphs and complete graphs by K. Archer, A. Diaz-Lopez, D. Glass and J. Louwsma (Study of critical groups in specific arithmetical structures).

And of course some classics:

Chip-firing and the critical group of a graph by N. L. Biggs;
On the sandpile group of dual graphs by R. Cori and D. Rossin;
Smith normal form and Laplacian by D. Lorenzini;
Critical groups for complete multipartite graphs and Cartesian products of complete graphs by B. Jacobson, A. Niedermaier and V. Reiner.


HI! The usual process around here is that you edit the old question that was closed and flag for re-opening, rather than self-deleting and making a new question. However, the question is still very broad, being a "what can you tell me about ____?", after give a general list of references. When you ask "what can you say?", it helps potential answerers to have a specific thing you need to know about, not just about a class of objects as a whole. Going on from here, just work with this post.

Dear David, I am very sorry for not following the forum rules properly. I am still trying to get accustomed to everything. How about this for the title: What additional insights can you provide about the structure of the Jacobian group of a Cayley graph?

It's ok to not know how the MO platform is intended to operate, that's for experienced users to guide new users to best practices on ^_^. But I can't say anything about the content of the question, since it is not my area. But I strongly urge you to try to boil your question down to the essentials, and explain what you already know, and what precisely you need. Best of luck!

Not about Cayley graphs. But might of some interest for other graphs: https://mathoverflow.net/a/212663/10446 leads to:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07529v1 leads to:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.5684
See also: https://mathoverflow.net/a/315725/10446

https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.06919
Sandpile Groups of Cayley Graphs of r2

Dihedral group: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669803001045 (2003) Sandpile group on the graph  of the dihedral group
Arnaud Dartois a ,  Francesca Fiorenzi b , Paolo Francini

Not about Cayley, but general graphs ---  Richard Stanley discusses graph Jacobians  here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.00166 , see also his slides on Smith Normal Form: https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/transparencies/seattle2016.pdf
